# Sqlalchemy limit/offset returns incorrect result for pagination

Tags: python, sql, database, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a correct query

```
    my_query = session.query(Task).join(
    Job, Job.id == Task.job_id
    ).join(
        User, User.id == Task.member
    )
```

After this I want to implement some sorting:

```
        sort_func = 'asc' if '-' not in data['sort'] else 'desc'
        sort_key = data['sort'].replace('-', '')
        sort_map = {
            'task_name': Task.name,
            'created_at': Task.created_at,
        }
        query = query.order_by(getattr(sort_map[sort_key], sort_func)())
```

Lets imagine that this query returns the following results:

```
   [{id: 1, task_name: 'Metallica'},{id: 2, task_name: 'soad'},{id: 3, task_name: 'elasticsearch'},{id: 4, task_name: 'bee'},{id: 5, task_name: 'one'},{id: 6, task_name: 'football'},{id: 7, task_name: 'mars'},{id: 8, task_name: 'hello'},{id: 9, task_name: 'apple'},{id: 10, task_name: 'car'},{id: 11, task_name: 'ford'}];
```

After this I want to implement pagination (with dynamic offset):

```
query = query.offset(offset).limit(5)
```

I expect that after first request my response is first five items from the list above:

```
   [{id: 1, task_name: 'Metallica'},{id: 2, task_name: 'soad'},{id: 3, task_name: 'elasticsearch'},{id: 4, task_name: 'bee'},{id: 5, task_name: 'one'}]
```

and after second request:

```
[{id: 6, task_name: 'football'},{id: 7, task_name: 'mars'},{id: 8, task_name: 'hello'},{id: 9, task_name: 'apple'},{id: 10, task_name: 'car'}]
```

But for the second page I get some items from the first page.
For example:

```
    [{id: 2, task_name: 'soad'},{id: 7, task_name: 'mars'},{id: 8, task_name: 'hello'},{id: 9, task_name: 'apple'},{id: 1, task_name: 'Metallica'}]
```

Does anybody know why offset/limit distorts my result?
Or maybe this isn't offset/limit problem

Comment: How are you generating your `offset` value? Is it being incremented by 1 or the value of your limit i.e. 5?

Comment: What database are you using and which SQLAlchemy version? I had a similar issue with MSSQL and SQLAlchemy <= 1.3.x.

Comment: SQLAlchemy==1.3.19 and Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.1
Database is Postgresql

Comment: I get offset value from my request and it increments/decrements by 5

Comment: You get the offset from the request? You're going to need to provide more code.